# How to stop a windows service, check if its been stopped, and start it up again using Cmd Line?

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I have a rather simple task to achieve but am a total noob at command line scripts. I have googled around and found some of the basic commands to interact with the services on a windows machine but nothing in aspects of checking whether a service is started or stopped. I'm hoping someone can help with a script that will stop 3 services, check to make sure all 3 are stopped, and once all are stopped..start them all back up again. I need to make sure all 3 are stopped before starting any of them back up. I know how to stop and start services but the rest is where i am stuck.

```
net Stop S1
net Stop S2
net Stop S3

//Check if all 3 are stopped

//If all 3 have been stopped successfully
net start s1
net start s2
net start s3
```

I have come up with this but dont think the syntax is correct...

```
net stop PriceIdxImport
net stop RawDataImportDB
net stop DBDailyTrxProcessService

set Pstate = sc query PriceIdxImport state
set Rstate = sc query RawDataImportDB state
set Dstate = sc query DBDailyTrxProcessService state

if Pstate == Inactive if Rstate == Inactive if Dstate == Inactive GOTO sub_StartServices

:sub_StartServices
net start PriceIdxImport
net start RawDataImportDB
net start DBDailyTrxProcessService
```

---

Alright i took the above script and altered it into a while loop..it doesnt do the loop correctly? It checked the status and then exits :(

```
  echo on
 net stop PriceIdxImport
 net stop RawDataImportDB
 net stop DBDailyTrxProcessService
 ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
 set Pstate = Sc query PriceIdxImport  |find /i "STOPPED"
 set Rstate = sc query RawDataImportDB |find /i "STOPPED"
 set Dstate = sc query DBDailyTrxProcessService |find /i "STOPPED"
 set Condition="false"

 while Condition="false";do if Pstate neq "" ( if Rstate  neq "" (if  Dstate neq ""          GOTO sub_StartServices));done
exit

:sub_StartServices
set Condition="true"
net start PriceIdxImport
net start RawDataImportDB
net start DBDailyTrxProcessService
```

Comment: Variable assignments in batch must be done like this: `set var=foo bar` (without spaces around the `=`).

Comment: Alright i changed the 3 set statements to have no spaces so it fits the var=xxx format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this script

```
echo on
:sub_StopServices    
net stop PriceIdxImport
net stop RawDataImportDB
net stop DBDailyTrxProcessService

set Pstate = Sc query PriceIdxImport  |find /i "STOPPED"
set Rstate = sc query RawDataImportDB |find /i "STOPPED"
set Dstate = sc query DBDailyTrxProcessService |find /i "STOPPED"

if Pstate neq "" ( if Rstate  neq "" (if  Dstate neq "" (GOTO sub_StartServices) else (GOTO sub_StopServices) ) else (GOTO sub_StopServices)) else (GOTO sub_StopServices)
exit
:sub_StartServices
net start PriceIdxImport
net start RawDataImportDB
net start DBDailyTrxProcessService
```

Comment: I'd recommend usingt `net start|stop` over `sc start|stop`, because the latter is non-blocking.

Comment: makes it all the more reason to use it. plus sc is specifically written for handling services...although at the end if day it boils down to ones style of coding :)

Comment: Whether non-blocking operations are desireable depends on the actual requirements/circumstances. In the OP's case I'd most certainly prefer a blocking operation, because it will spare me the trouble of checking the service status in a loop (and with a timeout).

Comment: Is there a way to put this into a while loop? Reason i am asking is because this script needs to run until all 3 have been stopped and only  then restart all 3. I need a loop for the case when say 2 go down but 1 stays up...it needs to stop all 3again and check all 3 again to make sure all 3 are down this iteration before exiting the loop and starting them back up.

Comment: net start/stop is blocking..so until service is down or has been down from before, it wont move to next line of script

Comment: alright cool i'll this updated script also! appreciate the quick responses!

Comment: The updated version is working :) much cleaner then my while loop version haha

Comment: well crap it's failing to check the status properly. 1 of the 2 services failed to stop but it went ahead and started the other 2 anyways :( thoughts?

Comment: it would show failure to stop only when service is already stopped which is the required state.

Comment: ahh there was an error in the shut down of the service that refused to be shut down. I got an unknown error when i tried stopping it, took 2 attempts manually to stop it. Once i stopped it manually it started up fine...it fails to stop this one service every time :( do i need sleeps between each stop or something? I'll try rearranging the net stop commands to see if that helps

Comment: Its either an internal service error or windows error that prevents it from being stopped haha, its a 3rd party service and on a test machine so im confident this script works given it works flawless on the other 2 services. I'll mark it as solved :D

Comment: I got a question haha..what does this return; sc query RawDataImportDB |find /i "STOPPED"? If the text stopped isnt found it returns 1 right? If it is found it returns 0? My reason for asking is because the loop seems to fail, It does not attempt to stop any service that failed to stop the first time through. It just continues on to restarting them and never loops back through the stop function :(

Comment: I just ran the net stop command 3 times on the service that is giving an error. It takes at least 2 attempts of net stop to successfully stop the service.. it then and only then should be restarted. The first iteration it says "service could not be stopped" an then gives a "present state error" on 2nd iteration and on the 3rd it reports that it has already been stopped(normal error). It should do this by using the loop but i had to manually re run the .cmd file 3 times to get these results.